# Многопоточность в C

Tags: c, многопоточность

Как реализована многопоточность в C на уровне языка?
Есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные библиотеки?

Comment: Так на уровне языка или на уровне библиотек?

Comment: Наверное, в первую очередь смотрите [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). Если хочется именно на уровне языка, смотрите [Cilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilk). А так: [Thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

Comment: очень мощная вещь Intel TBB, перешёл на неё с OpenMP, но это только C++

Comment: Ответ **никак**, стандарт языка Си не декларирует никакой многопоточности.

Comment: В C11 подвезли [`#include <threads.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread).

Comment: .. но не выгрузили. GCC пока не написал. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @AlexGlebe [Тут работает](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fzhfPf9TK). Но на MinGW действительно не взлетело.

Comment: на вашем примере получается только в gcc 10.1 написано. вряд-ли так быстро все будут линять  с POSIX `<pthread.h>`. особенно импорто замещение типа Байкала точно. @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 1):

В языке С существует библиотека для организации многопоточных программ:  **POSIX Threads API**

Как очевидно из названия, эта библиотека определяется в рамках стандарта POSIX и должна поддерживаться на любой системе, поддерживающей POSIX.

Конкретно в Linux эта библиотека называется *libpthread*.

Что бы ознакомиться с ней, можно использовать команду:

```
man 7 pthreads

ИМЯ
       pthreads - нити POSIX

ОПИСАНИЕ
       В POSIX.1 определён набор интерфейсов (функции, заголовочные файлы) для работы с нитями, более
       известными как нити POSIX или Pthreads. В одном процессе может быть несколько  нитей,  которые
       выполняют  одну  программу.  Эти нити работают с общей глобальной памятью (сегментами данных и
       кучи), но у каждой нити есть собственный стек (автоматические переменные).
```

Насколько мне известно, *POSIX Threads API* поддерживается и в Windows, но с некоторыми тонкостями.